# C++ explicit instantiation of template constructor of non-template class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, member, explicit-instantiation

I'm working on a C++ Fraction class that use pimpl idiom, my public header is something like (work in progress)

```
Fraction.h
```

code:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Fraction
{
public:
    Fraction();
    ~Fraction();

    template <typename N>
    Fraction(N numerator, bool normalize = true);
    template <typename N, typename D>
    Fraction(N numerator, D denominator, bool normalize = true);

    Fraction(Fraction&&);
    Fraction& operator=(Fraction&&);

    template <typename T>
    bool operator==(T const & other);
    template <typename T>
    bool operator!=(T const & other);

    std::string representation ();

private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};
```

I can have correct specialization in my cpp file using explicit instantiation for member (eg. comparison operator overload)

```
Fraction.cpp
```

partial code

```
template <typename T>
bool Fraction::operator==(const T& other)
{
    return pimpl->operator==(other);
}

template bool Fraction::operator==<int>(int const &);
template bool Fraction::operator==<float>(float const &);
template bool Fraction::operator==<double>(double const &);
template bool Fraction::operator==<Fraction>(Fraction const &);
```

But I have some VS2015 compiler error when I want do the same with the constructor:

```
template <typename N, typename D>
Fraction::Fraction(N num, D den, bool norm)
    : pimpl{ std::make_unique<impl<N,D>>(num, den, norm) }
{}

template Fraction::Fraction<int, int>(int, int, bool);
```

I get build error (in french):

```
C2143   erreur de syntaxe : absence de ';' avant '<' fraction.cpp [156]
C2059   erreur de syntaxe : '<'                      fraction.cpp [156]
```

The fraction.cpp line 156 is:

```
template Fraction::Fraction<int, int>(int, int, bool);
```

The error in english (approx. translation) :

```
C2143   syntax error : absence of ';' before '<'
C2059   syntax error : '<'
```

I've test some variation of the explicit instantiation but I can not find a solution. I hope this is allowed by the standard?

---

**EDIT** : To answer the comment of Sam Varshavchik, the cpp class integrate the private implementation of the Fraction class in the form of:

```
class Fraction::impl
{
public:
    Fraction::impl()
        : _num (0)
        , _den (1)
    {}

    ...

    template <typename N, typename D>
    Fraction::impl(N numerator, D denominator, bool normalize = true)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    ...
};
```

Here, no need explicit specialization of the template because is a .hpp class style.

---

**SOLUTION** (Thank to `Constructor` for is (so evident) solution)

```
template <typename N, typename D>
Fraction::Fraction(N num, D den, bool norm)
    : pimpl{ std::make_unique<impl>(num, den, norm) }
{}

template Fraction::Fraction(int, int, bool);
```

Just:

- Replace the `impl<N,D>` by `impl`.
- Remove the `<int, int>` in the template explicit instanciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax like this for explicit instantiation of templated contructors in C++:

```
template Fraction::Fraction<int, int>(int, int, bool);
                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should use the following simple syntax instead:

```
template Fraction::Fraction(int, int, bool);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
impl<N,D>
```

`impl` is not a template, it is a class:

```
class impl;
```

See? It's a declared class. It's not a template, and your compiler is rightfully upset that you're trying to tell it now that it's a template that must be instantiated with two template parameters, `N`, and `D`.

The intent of your code is unclear, so the correct course of action is not obvious. However, another problem is also obvious, which lies in your future: after you square away your compilation error, you will then find yourself immediately staring at a link failure, because [templates can only be implemented in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file), and not in the `.cpp` file, as you're trying to do. At least not without some additional work.

Comment: "At least not without some additional work" Here the additional work is already in place.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik - Thanks for your answer. I mention that the Fraction class is an pimpl idiom. In the cpp the private implementation is fully filled. I will add additionnal information to my question in few minutes.